# ServiceStack Caching No Ceremony Razor

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I have a simple website that is using the no ceremony razor views mostly for handling the layouts of a bunch of static pages.  This is on an azure web app.  The pages seem to load a little slower than I like (Azure has slow I/O), I'm wondering if there is a way to cache all these responses as they don't really need to be processed at all after compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [no ceremony razor pages](http://razor.servicestack.net/#no-ceremony) are executed directly and don't go through the normal request pipeline so there's no opportunity to cache their outputs.

You'd need to do something like converting it to a Razor View by moving it to the `/Views` folder, create a Request DTO with the same name as the page, then add a `[CacheResponse]` attribute on the Service like:

```
[Route("/pagename1")] class PageName1 {}
[Route("/pagename2")] class PageName2 {}

[CacheResponse(Duration = 3600)]
public class HtmlServices : Service
{
    public object Any(PageName1 request) => request;
    public object Any(PageName2 request) => request;
}
```

Which will cache the HTML Response outputs for the above pages for 1 hour.

Comment: That's what I was "afraid" of!  This (ability to cache them) would be a nice addition as they are noticeably slow on azure for a static page!

Comment: @lucuma If the pages are mostly static you could have better performance using a [static html file + ajax request](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts#loaded-via-ajax), the `default.html` page would be cachable and you could apply caching to the JSON Service to make it fast.

Comment: Sure. I'm just trying to keep it simple although perhaps a simple spa would be simpler in this case. Already converted it to services which was easy too and extremely fast.  Thank you for the feedback.